# Efficiently adding child nodes

Tags: javascript

I need to add `x` children to a div.  So far I'm just using:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) { 
    element.appendChild(document.createElement(‘div’));
}
```

But I feel like creating the same empty node every time is kinda redundant.  However...

```
var b = document.createElement('div');
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) { 
    element.appendChild(b);
}
```

Only seems to create a single child.

Answer (score 4):

If you call `appendChild` on a node that already exists and is attached to the DOM, then it is either directly moved to the new position, or first removed from the document tree, then inserted at the end of the parent element it was called on.

So the second code you gave basically keeps inserting and removing the same node to the same element, resulting in only one node at the end of the entire process.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to create a new node for each iteration if you want the nodes to be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't appending the same empty element every time - you are appending a *different* empty element.  Even though the elements might appear to be be identical in every respect, they are different instances.

If you want a more efficient way of appending a series of DIVs to an element then you might have more luck appending to the the innerHtml property of the element:

```
var appendHtml = "";
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    appendHtml += "<div></div>";
}
element.innerHTML += appendHtml;
```

There are more efficient ways of concatenating strings in JavaScript, however that sample illustrates the concept.

<sub>(Mandatory [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plug)</sub>